# Installing QGIS with Python 2 and Python 3 on OSX

Tags: qgis, installation, python-3, homebrew, python-2

I just installed qgis (and all the dependencies, etc.) on my Mac OSX 10.10 via homebrew.  Currently, I use both Python 2 and Python 3 on the machine.  Whenever I change the Python path [to open qgis], I can no longer use Python 3 in any of my py3 virtual environments until I unset the python path.

Has anyone found a good solution to having both Python2 + Python3 on their machine with qgis?

Comment: It is a simple problem of UNIX path. I have two versions of Python 2.7.x and a version of Python 3.5 which can run at the same time

Comment: How do you change the python path? I.e. make sure that you are not changing the path system-wide but only for the QGIS application.

Comment: It turned out to be that, Matthias Kuhn.  Thank you!